# SQL CASE STATEMENT if data exists for same ID is in both tables output data

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, case

I want to create a select query that checks for a certain value (example below: 'green') in table 1, if exists, it finds the same id in table 2 and displays that rows data.

```
table 1

id car
1  black
2  green

table 2

id  status
1   old
2  broken
```

So the result should be: 'broken'.

Heres my code:

```
SELECT TOP 100 car CASE WHEN table1.car IN ('green') THEN Table2.status END AS 'result'
FROM Table1.ID INNER JOIN Table2.ID
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.car, t2.status AS result
    FROM Table1 t1
        INNER JOIN Table2 t2
            ON t1.id = t2.id
    WHERE t1.car = 'green'
```

Answer (score 1):

why wouldn't this be just a join?

```
select c.id, c.car, s.status
from car c, status s
where c.id = s.id
and car = 'green' -- if desired
;
```